# "Weird, but the extension you are currently using could not be found" when debugging VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Attempting to run my VSCode extension locally shows the command I added to the menu, but for some reason fails to find the extension after attempting to invoke the command?

[image: an error in VSCode that says "Weird, but the extension you are currently using could not be found"]

Edit: Found the culprit! Missed a replacement of the old publisher and the mismatch was causing issues. It was in the extension.ts under KnownExtensionNames. Not having the new publisher name before the extension name was causing it to be unable to find the extension even though the functionality was still there.

Comment: have you made a typo in the name of the extension somewhere, look for the command you want to execute from the menu

Comment: Not quite but your comment helped me on the right track so thanks! Ended up having missed a reference to the old publisher that was causing the issue. Updated the post with the fix as well.